# How to change the modification date (The Metadata) of multiple files?

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, file-metadata, exif

I have a gallery folder with multiple images and videos, some of them has their modification date correct, and some of them has the month wrong.
I want to make a script that will change all the files in a certain folder with a modification month from January to June (or any other similar combination)
Example:

I have images dated (The EXIF metadata not the name) as follows:

```
05-Jan-2011
06-Jan-2011
07-Jan-2011
```

etc...

I want to keep the year and the day the same, but change only the month of all of them to June instead of Jan.

So they become (The EXIF metadata not the name) :

```
05-Jun-2011
06-Jun-2011
07-Jun-2011
```

etc....

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `modifcation date`? Is it the filename or the file metadata?

Comment: I mean the Metadata

Comment: Do you mean the file system's mtime metadata, or the image format's exif metadata or similar?

Comment: The exif metadata

Comment: I didn't realize you were talking about exif metadata therefore my answer is not useful here.

Comment: @userbash654 is the  file system's modification date metadata equivalent to exif metadada? If it is, then my answer could be useful.

Comment: What tool are you using that outputs `05-Jan-2011` instead of `2011-01-05` for the files modification date?

Answer (score 2):

**Update: If I am wrong with this answer please let me now.**

I'm not sure if `file system's modification date` metadata is equivalent to `exitf modification date` metadata. I tested with `exiftool` and the dates are equivalent, so it makes me think is I can use `touch` for manipulating that metadata.

**Solution:**

First you should get the modification date of the file by using `stat` command:

```bash
filedate=$(stat -c '%y' "/path/to/file" | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Now it will be replaced the month with another one. For that, you can use awk:

```bash
newDate=$(awk -v month="Jun" -F '-' '{print $1"-"month"-"$3}' <<< $filedate )
```

And with `touch` command you can change the modification date:

```bash
touch -m -d $newDate /path/to/file
#-m argument is used to change modification time
#-d is used to specify the new date
```

Finally, if you want to change files recursively you can use `find` and the code provided before should be in a script file:

**script.sh:**

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

filedate=$(stat -c '%y' "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1)

newMonth="Dec" #here you specify the month 
newDate=$(awk -v month=$newMonth -F '-' '{print $3"-"month"-"$1}' <<< $filedate )

touch -m -d $newDate $1
```

And with `find` you can use:

```bash
find /path/to/your_directory -type f -exec ./script.sh {} \;
```

**If you want to specify the month in the find command, you can pass it to the script.sh as parameter:**

Therefore, the code would now became:

**script.sh**

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

filedate=$(stat -c '%y' "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1)

newMonth="$2"
newDate=$(awk -v month=$newMonth -F '-' '{print $3"-"month"-"$1}' <<< $filedate )

touch -m -d $newDate $1
```

**find command**

```bash
find . -type f -exec ./script {} "Nov" \;
```

Comment: When you run `stat -c '%y'` does it really output `05-Jan-2011` instead of `2011-01-05` for the date format? If so, what platform are you on?

Comment: @EdMorton the  output is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and the month is represented by its number, so your second example `2011-01-05` is the correct format. By the way I'm using Linux and when I use `stat -c '%y'` I get something like this: `2022-02-22 21:06:07.324302454 -0600`

Comment: With `touch -d` I can specify the date in the format `DD-MM-YYYY` where the month can be represented by it's name or it's number

Comment: Actually, it'd fail with a number in that format, it'd have to be `YYYY-MM-DD`for `MM` to be a number. Thanks for confirming the `stat` output format. I'm trying to figure out where the OP is getting a month name abbreviation from.

Comment: @EdMorton oh yeah! you're right. What I cannot test is if those commands are POSIX compliant. I'm not sure if on macOS it might work

Comment: @EdMorton about the month I have that doubt too, but I think the OP is using something like `ls -l` because that returns the date like: `Jan 25  2021`

Comment: idk about POSIX or not but they would work the same on MacOS. Hopefully the OP isn't really parsing the output of ls (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for that info! it's useful! I would think that the OP is using some tool/command to convert the date in `DD-MM-YYYY` format.